# Python renew a function's definition of imported module and use renewed one in even functions of imported module

Tags: python

I have a `file1.py`:

```
def funcCommon1():
    pass
def file1Func1():
    funcCommon1()
    ....#other lines of code
```

and I have a `file2.py` which I have imported funcs of `file1.py`

```
from file1 import *
def file2FuncToReplacefuncCommon1():
    ....#some lines of code
def funcCommon1():#renewed or lets just say replaced `funcCommon1` definition
    file2FuncToReplacefuncCommon1()
```

but in `file1Func1`, `funcCommon1()` refers to `pass` defenition but I want to refer to `file2FuncToReplacefuncCommon1`.
I know in `file1.py`I cant do `from file2 import *` because it will go to infinite loop. or I dont want to pass `funcCommon1` as an argument to funcs like `file1Func1`. something like:

```
def file1Func1(funcCommon1):
    funcCommon1()
    ....#other lines of code
```

so is there any other way I can renew the definition of `funcCommon1` in `file1Func1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fundamentally not how Python works. What you call "renew" is simply defining a *new function* in a completely *different namespace.*

What you should do is *pass the function as an argument*. This is sane,  normal way to approach this.

But if you want something close to what you are doing, you can do this (totally not good thing) instead:

in file2.py:

```
import file1 # You shouldn't have been using starred imports to begin with

def file2FuncToReplacefuncCommon1():
    ... #some lines of code

file1.funcCommon1 = file2FuncToReplacefuncCommon1
```

And now,

```
file1.funcCommon2()
```

Will use your "renewed" function. Again, **this is really not a sane way to do this, you really should reconsider and just pass a function as an argument**.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this is called monkey patching. And I agree, you only do this when you need to as a workaround to modify someone else's library... or *maybe* for testing. You really shouldn't actively design your code to be used this way.

Comment: @CrazyChucky what are down sides to it?

Comment: @FarhangAmaji the fundamental problem with designing your program this was is that you are relying on mutable global state, which is a *classic* anti-pattern. It produces less modular code that is harder to reason about. You *really really* shouldn't do it.

Comment: @FarhangAmaji so just a simple example, whenever you look at the call `file1.funcCommon1()` in isolation, you don't know *what* the behavior is going to be -- it depends on the state which is hidden from you, but which you can modify. If instead, you were required to pass the function (the behavior!) to the call, then it is all clear *at the call site in isolation*, `file1.funcCommon2(some_function)`. In the former case you have to understand  *all the code execution that precedes the call to know what is going on*, in the latter, you can just look at the function call and know.